# Lot of exceptions on sentry from audio_service

Tags: flutter, audio-service

I see lot of errors related to this plugin on sentry. I want to know if it's normal and negligible or something wrong with my implementation. I use latest flutter stable with `audio_service: ^0.18.1`

Here's the errors I keep seeing:

> RuntimeException Unable to stop service
> com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService@3b9ce277:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long
> c.a.a.b.h2.n0()' on a null object reference

[image: sentry screenshot1]

> MissingPluginException MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method dispose on channel
> com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods.16f73255-9c2f-418c-9e6e-6ff96c5e33d3)

[image]

In my opinion, I think I need to manage lifecycle of the app and dispose the audio service. But I wanted to make sure if they are important or not.

Comment: One of the common causes of MissingPluginException is when you're using multiple isolates or FlutterEngines, and you have a plugin in your `pubspec.yaml` that hasn't been programmed to correctly run in multiple isolates/FlutterEngines. Unfortunately, the error message mentioning just_audio doesn't actually give any hints because generally that's not the real cause. It is impossible to track down the cause without going through all of your plugins and checking them (e.g. by disabling them.)

Comment: Thanks @RyanHeise, maybe one possible case is, user close the app and just audio wasn't present(null) to call dispose. I have no idea though.

Comment: Still, it is difficult to understand the real cause without knowing what other plugins you're using that manage isolates/FlutterEngines.

Comment: Hello, I have a similar issue. Have you found a way to resolve yours ?